# Proof that the q-Gaussian is derived by maximizing Tsallis entropy

Tags: statistics, entropy, statistical-mechanics

So I have to write a report paper for a course and I would like to prove that the q-Gaussian is the distribution which arises once one maximizes the Tsallis entropy.

But I face difficulties in proving it. Actually I am quite new to the field of Statistical Mechanics and not really familiar with the methods of going through a proof like that.

Could it be possible that someone providess a reference which provides the proof or show me how to actually maximize a distribution, so that I am able to start at least from that?

Thank you!

Comment: You should first understand what happens with the canonical entropy. Incidentally, is Tsallis entropy really needed?

Comment: @Jonas Well, if by needed you mean in general, that is quite a big discussion to be made here. But, yes it is needed since I have to make a report paper on this one :) But you are also right. I have to start from that. But I cannot prove that either. How to start? Any assistance?

Comment: Sure. I would suggest looking at http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.60.2398

Comment: @Jonas Again thank you for your help but I am afraid I do not have any access to that paper..